# Python ConnectN Board Game

Tags: python

So this is basically like Connect4 but in this case 5 game pieces in a row instead of 4. I am trying to write this code to check for horizontal wins but its not working and nothing is printing?

can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
game_board = [['_','_','_','_','_','_','_'],
         ['_','_','_','_','_','_','_'],
         ['_','_','_','X','_','_','_'],
         ['_','_','_','O','_','_','_'],
         ['_','X','O','O','O','O','O'],
         ['X','X','X','O','O','X','O']]

num_col= 7
num_row= 6
num_piece= 5
game_piece= 'O'

for r in range(num_row):
  for c in range(num_col-num_piece):
    index=0
    for i in range (num_piece):
      if game_board[r][c + index] == game_piece:
        index +=1
      else:
        break
      if index == num_piece:
        print('end game')
```

Answer (score 0):

If `c + index` is greater than 6, `game_board[r][c + index]` will throw that error. You should reduce how many columns you are checking to `num_col - num_piece` since it's impossible for a horizontal run that begins past that point to result in a win anyway.

```py
for r in range(num_row):
  for c in range(num_col - num_piece):
    ...
```

Comment: i fixed it but now nothing is printing :/

Comment: @vsc It's printing nothing because you are checking `index == num_piece`, but `index` is every value in `range(0, num_piece)`, the maximum value of which is `num_piece - 1`. As such, `index == num_piece` will never be true.